# Possible winning sequence

Tags: combinatorics

Find number of words of length n that contain an even quantity of letters G and don't start with G ,also k denotes number of letters.

Example: n= 1 k=4   Ans is: 3

I know this is a permutation/combination question and want to formulate the logic for different values of n and k.Help me to formulate the logic behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the number of words of length $n$ that contain an even quantity of letters $G$ and don't start with $G$

This is the same as $k-1$ multiplied by the number of words of length $n-1$ that  contain an even number of letters $G$.

denote by $e(m)$ the number of words of length $m$ that contain an even number of letters $G$ and by $o(m)$ the number of words of length $m$ that contain an odd number of letters $G$.

Then $e(m+1)=(k-1)e(m)+o(m)$.This is because there are $e(m)$ words of length $m+1$ ending with every word different than $G$ and $o(m)$ words of length $m+1$ ending in $G$.

Since $e(m)+o(m)=k^m$ we get $e(m+1)=(k-2)e(m)+k^m$

We shall prove $e(m)=\dfrac{k^m+(k-2)^m}{2}$ by induction on $m$.

It is clear $e(1)=k-1=\frac{k+k-2}{2}$

Suppose $e(m)=\dfrac{k^m+(k-2)^m}{2}$ then using our recursion we get $e(m+1)=(k-2)\dfrac{k^m+(k-2)^m}{2}+k^m=\dfrac{k^{m+1}+(k-2)^{m+1}}{2}$ as desired.

Therefore the final answer to your question is $(k-1)e(n-1)=(k-1)\dfrac{k^{n-1}+(k-2)^{n-1}}{2}$

Comment: that's a nice explantion.Thank you. I wonder how to approach these kind of problems since i am not good at such questions...any suggestions would be welcome and helpful for me:)

Comment: I am only good at these things because I practice. I has already seen a problem similar to this one. When counting many times you can find a direct formula easily. However in this case I could not, so I found a recurrence, after computing some small values of the recurrence and observing how the recurrence increased I came up with a hypothesis of what it might be, and then I proved it by induction. The hint is to practice, perhaps I wouldn't have been able to answer it had I not seen something similar before.

Comment: can you suggest some links or books or anything that i can start reading/practicing...i would love to improve myself:)

Comment: This book is sublime, it is available online, and it provides lots of practice http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/news-resources/electronic/kpbogart/ComboNoteswHints11-06-04.pdf

Comment: thank you i would see to it:) and also in your final formula n should be replaced by n-1. thank you again

Answer (score 1):

The not winning the first year is a pointless little complication. For $n\gt 1$, the answer is  $k-1$ times the number of ways G can win an even number of times in $m=n-1$ games. We find an expression for that.

Perhaps G wins $0$ games. That can happen in $\binom{m}{0}(k-1)^m$ ways.

Perhaps G wins $2$ games. That can happen in $\binom{m}{2}(k-1)^{m-2}$ ways.

Perhaps $G$ wins $4$ games. That can happen in $\binom{m}{4}(k-1)^{m-4}$ ways.

And so on. We need to add together all of these.

Now comes the trick. Note that by the Binomial Theorem we have
$$(x+1)^m=\binom{m}{0}x^m +\binom{m}{1}x^{m-1}+\binom{m}{2}x^{m-2}+\binom{m}{3}x^{m-3}+\binom{m}{4}x^{m-4}+\cdots.\tag{1}$$ 
Note also that
$$(x-1)^m=\binom{m}{0}x^m -\binom{m}{1}x^{m-1}+\binom{m}{2}x^{m-2}-\binom{m}{3}x^{m-3}+\binom{m}{4}x^{m-4}-\cdots.\tag{2}$$
Add (1) and (2), and divide by $2$. We get
$$\frac{(x+1)^m+(x-1)^m}{2}=\binom{m}{0}x^m+\binom{m}{2}x^{m-2}+\binom{x}{4}x^{m-4}+\cdots.$$
Finally, set $x=k-1$.

Comment: thanks for your answer too...though your's explanation is different but good and gives same formula as of @bananarama:)

Comment: You are welcome. It is useful to see different approaches, for each one adds to your collection of tools.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mechanical way of solving such problems on patterns (by making use of a computer, would be tedious to do by hand).

Describe a directed graph:

\begin{align*}
  A &= \begin{bmatrix}
 & \mathrm{I} & \mathrm{S} & \mathrm{O} & \mathrm{E} \\
\mathrm{I} & 0 & k-1 & 0 & 0 \\
\mathrm{S} & 0 & 0 & 1 & k-1 \\
\mathrm{O} & 0 & 0 & k-1 & 1 \\
\mathrm{E} & 0 & 0 & 1 & k-1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

where the states are

I : The initial state

S : The state on entering first alphabet, having no G.

O : The state on entering odd number of G's.

E : The state on entering even number of G's.

and the number of ways of entering that state are the entries in the matrix $A$.

We can now deduce the generating functions for all the entries in the matrix by computing $\left(I-x\, A\right)^{-1}$, and the entry of our interest is
fourth column in the first row. Hence, the required generating function:

\begin{align*}
  G(x) &= \left(I-x\, A\right)^{-1}[0,3] \\
  \implies G(x) &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1-x}{1-k\, x}+\frac{1+x}{1-(k-2)\, x}\right)-1
\end{align*}
Extracting $[x^n]$ gives:
\begin{align*}
  f_n &= \frac{1}{2}\left(k^n-k^{n-1}+(k-2)^n+(k-2)^{n-1}\right) \\
  &= \frac{1}{2} (k-1)\left(k^{n-1}+(k-2)^{n-1}\right)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

You could build a recursion.  Let $E(n)$ be the number of ways to have $G$ win an even number of times, and $O(n)$ the number of ways to have $G$ win an odd number of times.

Start off with $E(1)=k-1$ and $O(1)=0$.

Then can you find a formula for $E(n)$ in terms of $E(n-1)$ and $O(n-1)$?

That is a start, but there is still the question of solving the recursion.